# Cookie isn't setting properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, jwt

I'm making a login system using express/react/mongoose. I'm using the JWT algorithm. The login part works. When I refresh the page, the refresh route is triggered and it works. However, when I refresh the page again, it sends me back. The cookie deletes on the first refresh. I have diagnosed the issue of this behavior: mongoose doesn't find the document properly. The user variable logs properly the first time. However, on the second time, it logs as null. (React sends two requests.) It's definitely a server problem. Help would be appreciated.

```
const refresh = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const cookies = req.cookies;

    if (!cookies?.jwt) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized user" });

    const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;

    console.log(refreshToken);

    res.clearCookie('jwt', { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'None', secure: true });

    const user = await Users.findOne({ refreshToken }).exec();

    console.log(user);

    if (!user) {
        jwt.verify(
            refreshToken,
            process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
            async (err, decoded) => {
                if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);

                const user = await Users.findOne({ username: decoded.username }).exec();
                user.refreshToken = [];
                
                await user.save();
            }
        );

        return res.sendStatus(403);
    }

    const newRTArray = user.refreshToken.filter(rt => rt !== refreshToken);

    jwt.verify(
        refreshToken,
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        asyncHandler(async (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                user.refreshToken = [...newRTArray];
                await user.save();
            }

            if (err || user.username !== decoded.username) return res.sendStatus(403);

            const accessToken = generateToken({
                "UserInfo": {
                    "username": user.username,
                    "role": user.role
                }
            }, "access");

            const newRT = generateToken({
                username: user.username
            }, "refresh");

            user.refreshToken = [...newRTArray, newRT];
            await user.save();

            res.cookie('jwt', newRT, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'None', maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 });

            res.json({ role: user.role, accessToken });
        })
    );
});
```

EDIT: After diagnosing a bit more, I figured out the root cause of the problem. The cookie isn't getting updated on the second time react sends the request. However, the cookie adding part of my code looks fine.

EDIT #2: After some more debugging, I found out the specific issue, but I don't know how to fix it. React sends two of the same requests for some reason. Both requests have the same cookie because they're the same request. The first request goes through. However, the second doesn't bugging the whole program.

Comment: i think the problem is related to the frontend, as when you refresh a token you invalidate the previous token resulting to have on your second double request an error

Comment: Yeah I fixed it by making it only send one request